# How do I change default folder names in home directory?

Tags: home-directory, translation

How to change default folder names in home directory? My system (Ubuntu 14.04) was translated to Polish, and I changed to English, but left the names of default folders in Polish when asked. Now I want to change them to English, how to do that?

Comment: See `man xdg-user-dirs-update` for in depth explanation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` where you can manually set the default folder names / directories. Don't forget to rename the actual folders likewise as well.